# Store a dictionary of dictionaries in a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

Suppose I have a dictionary of dictionaries containing pairwise comparisons:

```
 dict_of_dict = {"apple":{"apple":1, "orange":.5, "banana":.7}, "orange":{"orange":1, "apple": .3, "banana":.8}, "banana":{"banana":1, "apple":.7, "orange":.8}}
```

Each embedded dictionary could contain ~200k entries.

One (terrible) approach to storing this in MySQL would be to create two tables *fruit* and *fruit mappings* where *fruit* stores an id for each fruit and *fruit mappings* stores each pairwise score.

*fruit* is a two column table with an id and a fruit:

```
 fruit_id fruit
 0        apple
 1        orange
 2        banana
```

*fruit mappings* maps the ids from *fruit* to the scores for each pairwise comparison.

```
    fruit_id_A   fruit_id_B    score

       0               0         1        
       0               1        .5
       0               2        .7
```

...and so on for fruit_ids 1 and 2. You can see the obvious problem when dealing with ~200k entries. In the actual application we won't have ~200k**2 rows since only a subset of fruit is compared, but even assuming that 50,000 fruits receive scores that would give us 10,000,000,000 rows.  Does someone have a better approach?

Comment: Could you structure the table so each row represents one of your original dictionaries (a whole set of scores) and each column represents one of the possible fruits? That would give you a single table with 200k rows.  You'd be able to tell the 'reference fruit' for the row since it looks from your example like that always has a value of 1, but if that is not reliable you'd have to add a separate column for the reference fruit.

Answer (score 2):

> One (terrible) approach to storing this in MySQL would be to create two tables fruit and fruit mappings where fruit stores an id for each fruit and fruit mappings stores each pairwise score.

This is not a terrible approach, but the sensible approach for relational databases.

If and only if your set of fruits will never change, the you could use only one table, identifying the fruit and an array over float holding all its scores. But you need to know which index of the array maps to which other fruit.

I would go for the obvious relational approach. What is so bad about having 200M rows, if you index the columns you need to access, there won't be a performance problem either.

Comment: Okay, 200m rows isn't terrible, but the subset could be as high as 50,000 (I've edited the original post to reflect this) so then we'd have 200k * 50k = 10,000,000,000 rows.

Comment: Actually, no matter how you store it, the volume won't change.

Comment: OOC: I didn't even know there existed 200,000 different fruits... (OK, I guess it is just a placeholder example.)